# Form input to accept array of strings

Tags: forms, input-fields, input

For a form, I want to accept a list of text inputs (e.g. "what baby names do you like?"). It's not a multi-select situation because there is not list of default values (the user could make up unknown baby names).

I could put a text input, and a "+" button nearby so they can add more text boxes. But requires some implementation.

I could show a single text input and tell the user to enter a comma-separated list. It's really easy implementation-wise, but obviously not as good a user experience as typing separate answers in separate boxes.

Is there a good and/or standard way to handle this situation?

(StackExchange has an example of this type of thing with their "Tags" list when asking a question, but they have a list of expected values which should be used in general.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `+` button does not only require implementation but also requires (for most people)

- mouse move to the button
- mouse click on the button
- mouse move back to the textfield
- mouse click on the textfield

I consider that as too much effort for the user.

While I have seen all kinds of data separation, including space and comma, I personally don't like it.

- Spaces in this context may not make sense at all, if you allow multiple names, e.g. German "Hans Peter" or "Karl Heinz".
- Commas are easy to miss. They only have a few pixels

Considering all this, I'd say a clean approach would be to use newlines. It looks nice like a list, it's a clear separation, it's easy to understand and does hardly require any effort except typing the word.

Example:

```
Michelle
Lucas Carl
Jerry
Henry
Samantha Martine
```

Answer (score 2):

To minimize users' physical (`+` pressings) and cognitive (mental) efforts, you can try the approach:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAAezG.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

**Pro:**

- The list of most popular names (according to [stats data](https://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/)) allows choice, instead of typing
- Pre-defined list is based on stats, so it can work quite well for average user
- Text area allows manual entry, and placeholder shows the format

**Con:**
Users' input can be biased, as you provide pre-defined list of options